# I am confused with Segmentation fault (core dumped)

Tags: c++

I use Fedora 39 and  gnu compiler g++ (GCC) 13.2.1 20231205 (Red Hat 13.2.1-6).
Why does the following code return: [Segmentation fault](https://godbolt.org/z/h4qvGfcde) (core dumped)

```
# include <iostream>
# include <fstream>
# include <string>

using namespace std;

int main (int argc, char** argv)
{
    string stri = "";
    cout << "Enter some characters: ";
    getline(cin, stri);
    cout << "You entered: " << stri << endl;
    clog << "This is the output to a terminal \"clog\"! " << stri << endl;
    ofstream out ("clog.txt");
    if (out) {
        clog.rdbuf(out.rdbuf());
    }
    else
    {
        cerr << "This is the output to a terminal \"cerr\"" << stri << endl; 
    }
    clog << "This is the output to a file \"clog\"! " << stri << endl; 
    
    return 0;
}
```

output:
Enter some characters: re
You entered: re
This is the output to a terminal "clog"! re
Segmentation fault (core dumped)

The code below works OK

```
# include <iostream>
# include <fstream>
# include <string>

using namespace std;

int main (int argc, char** argv)
{
    string stri = "";
    string stri1 = ""; // WITH THIS THERE IS NO MISTAKE, stri1 is not used anywhere
    cout << "Enter some characters: ";
    getline(cin, stri);
    cout << "You entered: " << stri << endl;
    clog << "This is the output to a terminal \"clog\"! " << stri << endl;
    ofstream out ("clog.txt");
    if (out) {
        clog.rdbuf(out.rdbuf());
    }
    else
    {
        cerr << "This is the output to a terminal \"cerr\"" << stri << endl;
    }
    clog << "This is the output to a file \"clog\"! " << stri << endl; 
    
    return 0;
}
```

output:
Enter some characters: re
You entered: re
This is the output to a terminal "clog"! re

In both cases the message is correct written to the file

Comment: I ran the second code snippet as well, even for that "Segmentation Fault" appears. So I don't think it works perfectly in second case as well

Comment: I can't replicate your error. Is the code you show the actual code you build and run? How do you build? Are you sure you're building the code you show (have you saved the file before building)? If you add a deliberate error in the code (like removing a semicolon) do you get the appropriate error when building? Please [edit] your question to add more information (like the exact command you use to build).

Comment: Unrelated: Instead of `string stri = "";` just write `string stri;`

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude Here is [demo](https://godbolt.org/z/h4qvGfcde) with segfault.

Comment: I did  verbatim copy of your code, get warnings for the unused `argc` and `argv` variables when building (with sanitizers), and ran it on my system without any crash. Which points to *undefined behavior*. If you catch the crash in a [debugger](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25385173/what-is-a-debugger-and-how-can-it-help-me-diagnose-problems), where in your code does it happen?

Answer (score 1):

Your program has undefined behavior due to double destruction of the underlying `streambuf` object.

`std::ostream` frees memory for the streambuf object in its destructor. In your code the same `streambuf` is attached to `clog` and `out`, resulting in double free.

The fix is to restore the original `streambuf` before you return.

```
int main (int argc, char** argv)
{
    std::string stri;
    std::cout << "Enter some characters: ";
    std::getline(cin, stri);
    std::cout << "You entered: " << stri << std::endl;
    std::clog << "This is the output to a terminal \"clog\"! " << stri << std::endl;
    std::ofstream out ("clog.txt");
    std::streambuf* buf = nullptr;
    if (out) {
        buf = std::clog.rdbuf(out.rdbuf());
    }
    else
    {
        std::cerr << "This is the output to a terminal \"cerr\"" << stri << std::endl; 
    }
    std::clog << "This is the output to a file \"clog\"! " << stri << std::endl; 
    if(buf)
        std::clog.rdbuf(buf);
    return 0;
}
```